# Custom simplification of symbolic definite integral with regards to bounds

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I would like to rewrite symbolic definite integrals such that the bounds are always positive.

For example :

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \mathrm{d} x \rightarrow \int_0^\infty \left[ f(x) + f(-x) \right] \mathrm{d} x$

I know that in *Mathematica*, you can provide a custom complexity function to [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) in order to get a result in a specific form.

I was wondering if this could be applied in some way to my problem. Unfortunately, my google search for this kind of problems came up empty. As a first step, it would be really helpful if anyone knew a function that returns the bound of a symbolic integral.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Often the internals of `Integrate` will do this anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but in my case I am really looking for a rewriting of the expression. The integrand is undefined at this point and the goal is really to automatically rewrite an arbitrary integral in terms of only integrals with positive bounds.

Comment: `integral[[2]]` will give the bounds of a univariate integral.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear, what precisely you are after. My impression is that you have some expressions like, say,

```
Integrate[(f[x]*k[x]^2)/g[x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

or more complex, but with undefined functions inside, and always with the integration from minus- to plus infinity. And you would like to transform them. If this is right, try the following function:

```
    rewr[expr_] := 
 Integrate[expr[[1]] + (expr[[1]] /. x -> -x), {x, 0, ∞}]
```

Examples:

```
rewr[Integrate[(f[x]*k[x]^2)/g[x], {x, -∞, ∞}]]

rewr[Integrate[g[x]/Ai[x], {x, -∞, ∞}]]
```

[image]

Have fun!